# Software problems with "Dell B1265dfw Mono MFP" printer and scanner on Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing, dell, scanner

I can't install the scanner drivers of my Dell B1265dfw. I "installed" the official Drivers for OS Deployment of my "[Dell B1265dfw Mono MFP](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ie/product-support/product/dell-b1265dfw/drivers)" and the icons of the application appeared on my Kubuntu 21.10. But it didn't open any application. After that, I had big problems with other applications in my Kubuntu, mainly I couldn't open Windows in my Virtualbox (apparently they were not related with the printer driver affair!). After different changes, I reinstalled all my OS (Kubuntu 21.10). And the same problem repeated when installing the official Drivers (affecting other applications, mainly Virtualbox). Finally, I reinstalled my Kubuntu 21.10 (3rd time) and I just installed the Dell printer driver (with the ppd file), but I couldn't install the scanner.

Comment: The Dell B1265dfw. is an IPP/AirPrint device. You do not need the vendor software as 21.10 should have all that is needed for printing and scanning. See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting.

Comment: This is fantastic. It solved my problem. I didn't know this option. Very easy! The official information of Dell, [here](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ie/000178977/configuring-and-using-airprint-on-compatible-dell-laser-printers#Three). Thanks!